# Kong gateway with kong-oidc plugin and react application hitting rate limit in IDP (Okta)

Tags: rate-limiting, kong, pkce, kong-plugin, kong-oidc

**About Setups :-**

1. My kong gateway is setup with [kong-oidc](https://luarocks.org/modules/phirvone/kong-oidc) plugin (free one)
2. I defined `introspection_endpoint`, `client_id`, `client_secret`, `discovery` and other necessary configs for `kong-oidc` in the gateway setup
3. UI is react SPA application
4. React app uses `PKCE` auth flow for login to IDP (Okta).

**My plan and expectation :-**

1. React app initiates login process (PKCE flow) and get `access_token` without kong involvement at all. This is done.
2. Send `access_token` from above step in the subsequent api request calls
3. I assumed `kong-oidc` plugin will validate the `access_token` using discovery document defined in the config and will forward the request to the upstream service.

**Issue I am having :-**

Application is hitting api call rate limit to Okta. But we are not explicitly making any call to Okta. Seems like `kong-oidc` plugin is making call to validate `access_token` on every request.

**What I am NOT doing :-**

1. We are `NOT` using `Kong authentication session cookie` at all as we are using PKCE auth flow and authentication is completely handle in UI itself.

**Questions :-**

2. Using PKCE flow in the SPA app is not correct with Kong gateway + kong-oidc plugin?
3. Should I use `Kong authentication session cookie` instead of PKCE flow? If so `Kong authentication session cookie` is the only way in kong gateway + kong-oidc world?